# Time Stretching and Pitch shifting with IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, core-audio, openal, audiounit

**In short:**
   How to do Time Stretching and Pitch Shifting in iOS?

> In Detail:

**What am i trying to do?**

The **app** will **show** the **video thumbnails** to the users to **select a certain range of frames** from the video file.

I have to **Apply the ramp slow Mo**, **only** to the **selected duration or frames** of the video.

**Ramp Slow Mo:** (**Time Stretching + Pitch shifting**) **dynamically**. I have to vary the Time and pitch in a for loop say for some 10 iteration. Its nothing but the behaviour of English letter "U". So, i will increase the time and pitch and decrease them.

**How am I trying:**

1. **Finding the Start/End time** for the user selected videos.
2. **Splitting the video and audio** separately through **AVFoundation Mutable Composition.**
3. **For Video:** Applying **Time Stretching** for only for the duration in **between Start/End time.** **No problem** in it,Its happening as i expect.
4. **For Audio:** Doing **Time Stretching and Pitch shifting dynamically**, which is also for the selected time frame. I am **using Dirac** for this. **Now, i would like to use IOS SDK itself**.
5. **Merging** audio and video post slow mo as a file and storing it.

**Analysis:**

Hitherto, I've found that **OpenAl** or **Audio Units**(Using **AUVarispeed** alone or **AUTimePitch** and **Time Rate** together) can help.
After splitting the video and audio, i will have the audio **URL** to proceed further, either with OpenAL or Audio Units.

**My questions:**

1. Can anybody help me to **avoid Dirac**(ref bullet 4)? So how to do Time Stretching and Pitch shifting dynamically?
2. How to do **only for the selected frame**s (in between start and end time)?
3. I am not sure how to **combine** **AVFoundataion's** URL **with OpenAL or Audio Unit's buffer** and after slow mo effect, **how to merge finally with AVFoundation's video reference URL**?

Any kind of reference or sample codes helps a lot.

Comment: Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Did you ever make any progress on this?